# mongoose find by ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm defining a mongoose schema like this

```
var accountPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  account: {
    id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Account' }
  },
  post: { 
   id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post' }
  }
});

app.db.model('AccountPost', accountPostSchema);
```

When a user(account holder) create a post, I save the post in a Post schema and get the 'postId'. Then I save the 'postId' and the 'accountId'
in the above accountPostSchema like this

```
var fieldsToSet = {
  post: {
    id: postId
  },
  account: {
    id: accountId
  }
};

db.models.AccountPost.create(fieldsToSet, function(err, accountPost) {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  }

  // handle success
});
```

After entering few postId's and accountId's, I see the following results in the mongo shell

```
> db.accountposts.find({})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5835096d63efc04da96eb71e"), "post" : { "id" : ObjectId("5835096d63efc04da96eb71d") }, "account" : { "id" : ObjectId("5833c920c868d7264111da69") }, "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("583509e12052c7a2a93c4027"), "post" : { "id" : ObjectId("583509e12052c7a2a93c4026") }, "account" : { "id" : ObjectId("5833c920c868d7264111da69") }, "__v" : 0 }
```

Now how do I find all the matching 'Posts' given an accountId? (not the postId's)

For example if I the accountId is 583509e12052c7a2a93c4026, I need to find Posts with Post._id=5835096d63efc04da96eb71d and Post._id=583509e12052c7a2a93c4026

What is the query I should run to get the matching Posts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, you should follow this way to get all the posts associated with particular accountid.

```
db.accountposts.find({'account.id' : accountId})
.populate('post.id')
.exec();
```

Answer (score 3):

First, I would suggest changing your Schema to the following

```
var accountPostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  account: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Account'
  },
  post: { 
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Post'
  }
});
```

This actually makes more sense, especially when you try to populate the subdocuments.  Actually, I would say this Schema is useless.  Why don't you define your `Post` schema like the following?

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  poster: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Account'
  },
  message: String
});
```

If you use the latter code, you could execute the following query to get all posts by a particular user:

```
db.posts.find({poster: accountId}, function(dbErr, userPosts) {
  if(dbErr) {
    // Handle the error.
  }

  // Do something with the posts by accountId in the array userPosts.
});
```

The advantages of removing the `id` field from `poster` becomes clear once you try to populate `poster`.  If you defined `poster` as an object with the field `id` and try to populate it, you will need to access data about the poster as such:

```
posterName = retrievedPost.poster.id.name;
```

Alternatively, by just making the `poster` field an `ObjectId` directly, you can access the populated user more directly:

```
posterName = retrievedPost.poster.name;
```

Comment: Your schema makes more sense. I should change to this. Thanks for the suggestion.